# Nuance of たましい?

Tags: meaning

**たましい** is defined as "*soul, spirit*". But, both of those words have so much nuance and usages...

Does a person's **たましい** persist after death?
Could **たましい** be used metaphorically such as `She has the spirit of a lion and goes for the jugular at the first sign of weakness.`.

**たましい** must be so nuanced. Please explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. 魂【たましい】 is something that is believed to persist after one's body perishes. After death, a 魂 may go to Heaven or Hell, or it may float around on earth ([Hitodama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitodama)), or it may be drained or eaten by monsters in fantasy works. It's a rather "occult" term. To refer to *mind* as opposed to *body* in academic and/or serious writings, 精神 is usually preferred.
2. 魂 also metaphorically refers to the essential part of something, someone's essential mindset. 「ライオンの魂 (the spirit of a lion)」「侍魂【さむらいだましい】 (spirit of *samurai*)」
3. A 魂 can sometimes stay inside artistic works, speeches, etc. 「魂のない小説 (soulless novel)」「魂のこもった声 (soulful vocal)」

So putting other very rare usages aside, Japanese 魂 can basically be translated either as *spirit* or *soul*. Dictionaries say English *soul* sometimes refer to *heart* or even *person* (eg "a kind soul"), but that's not possible with 魂.

Comment: wow. To have such an abstract concept  so directly translatable is absolutely amazing.